# How can I make LESS build CSS files whilst maintaining their folder structure in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: build, less, sublimetext2

I'm trying to setup my projects to all compile LESS the same way. Currently, I have my source files in their own folder. In that folder the modules are categorized into different sub-folders. (e.g. less/reset.less, less/variables.less, less/module/nav.less, less/layout/inline.less, etc.)

I want my build file to compile these files into another folder, but maintain the sub-folder structure. So:

- less/mixins.less -> css/reset.css
- less/module/nav.less -> css/module/nav.css
- less/layout/inline.less -> css/layout/inline.css

```
"cmd": ["lessc", "$file", "${file_path}/../css/${file_base_name}.css", "--verbose"],
```

Comment: didn't try it out, but it seeems that [this configuration](https://github.com/berfarah/LESS-build-sublime/blob/master/LESS-rewriteDir.sublime-build-choice) might work

Comment: You'll want to take the recommendation from the less build mentioned in Roberto's comment and do something like this:
`"cmd": ["lessc", "$file", "${file_path/(.*)less(.*)/\\1css\\2/}/${file_base_name}.css", "--verbose"],
`